# About Counting %

Tags: php

I Have 3 Fields In Database

```
Total_Points 
Earned_Point
Progress
```

Lets Say There's A Game

I Got 800 Point From 1000

```
Total_Points = 1000
Earned_Point = 800
Progress = 80%
```

I Counted The Progress (( 80% )) Manually

How Can I Count It Automatically With PHP ?

To Get The `%` Automatically ?

Comment: Progress = 100 * Earned_Point / Total_Points

Comment: @Nikola: it would be really funny if someone added bounty

Comment: Yeah, but look, I really don't believe this - people are upvoating the question!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that first you need to fetch this from database and than you can do calculation and store in the database

for calculating  use this

```
(Earned_Point * 100) / Total_Points
```

Answer (score 6):

Ugh, that's basic of mathematics...

```
Earned_Point * 100 / Total_Points
```

Comment: :) Thanks For Answer And Dont Feel Guilty Lol

Answer (score 2):

Try like

```
Progress = 100 * (Earned_Point / Total_Points)
```

Comment: You can give typecasting with either int or float as per your needs

Comment: please dont ask anyone to accept the answer given by self ...heheh